# How Convert list(row) to Json in python

Tags: python, sql, json, type-conversion

class JSONFormatter:

```
def convert(data:list):
    veri_dict = {item[0]: item[1] for item in data}
    json_veri = json.dumps(veri_dict, indent=4)
    return json_veri
```

I'm trying to get data from a database with select and convert it to json format.

I create this class and this convert method is working but this method works correctly when I pull data from a table with only id and url, it does not work when I pull data from another table, for example, a table with 5 columns.

Is there a way to solve this, and when creating the json file, I want to have the name of the column I pulled from that table instead of item[0]. Is this possible?

"I used translate, I hope I explained correctly."

convert list(row) to json.

[this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZOgG.png)

Comment: what is `row`? What is the *type* that you want to convert to a dictionary? Obviouly something you are getting back from some database driver, but are we supposed to just guess? Why don't you provide *the specifics of your situation*?

Comment: I'm talking about the data type returned from the fetchall() function result = cursor.fetchall() like this

Comment: *the* fetchall function? Which one? Again, are **we supposed to guess**? What library are you using? Why don't you just provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Since you are new here, you should check out [ask] and the [help]

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data = []
        for row in data:
            row_dict = {}
            for i in range(len(columns)):
                row_dict[columns[i]] = row[i]
            json_data.append(row_dict)
        json_str = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)
        return json_str
```

i solved, this is code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).